# Spring boot actuator/http.server.requests endpoint not working

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I have a demo spring boot application with actuator enabled in it.

`/metrics`, `/health` endpoints are working fine.
When I am trying to access `/actuator/http.server.requests` it is throwing 404.

Am I missing something ? Below is the demo code in git repo.
Thanks

https://github.com/imsprathap/actuatorDemo

Comment: Have you included this property `management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*`?

Comment: Yes, I have included. https://github.com/imsprathap/actuatorDemo/blob/master/src/main/resources/application.properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL is not correct.

It is

```
http://localhost:8080/actuator/metrics/http.server.requests
```

Comment: /actuator/metrics/http.server.requests is working thanks.

Comment: I actually clicked on the link provided under /metrics. It re-directs to `/actuator/http.server.requests`

Comment: Which Spring Boot Version?

Comment: version - 2.1.13.RELEASE